# UIScrollView loses 'bounce' effect without any reason

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I created an app for iPad which lets you navigare through some presentations... there are two views: The list of presentations and the view which shows you the presentation.
When a user selects a presentation (in PresentationListController), I show the presentation in the other view (PresentationViewController).
The PresentationViewController contains a UIScrollView with a list of pages... the problem is that after some time, without a recurring event which causes this problem, the UIScrollView 'loses' its capacity to bounce... so the scrolling is not smooth and it's like scrolling a rigid view without that fancy bounce effect... The user is still able to scroll but the effect is very ugly. The problem is that, the problem remains even if I go back the the PresentationListController and select a new PresentationViewController... the new presentation which is shown, have this problem.
I thought it was due to the fact that the navigationcontroller kept the UIView in memory and reused it whenever I opened a new presentation, but this is not the case because I debugged and saw that when I change the presentation, the dealloc method is called on the PresentationViewController.

So, how can I manage this problem?

***EDIT***

I found how to reproduce it: I am doing an animiation to open the list of pages, and an animation to close it. When I open a presentation which contains lots of pages (so that the contentSize of the UIScrollView > the width of the UIScrollView), I get no problem. But When I open and close the pages list in a presentation which only has one page, the problem begins. I wrote the code I am using to perform the animation+

here is the code I am using to perform the animation which opens and closes the pages list:

```
- (IBAction)showPagesView:(id)sender {
    if (pagesListVisible) {
            [self resetNavigationControls];
        } else {
            [self resetNavigationControls];
            scvPages.frame = CGRectMake(0, 960, 768, 0);
            scvPages.alpha = 0.0f;

            [btnPages setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
                scvPages.frame = CGRectMake(0, 760, 768, 200);
                scvPages.alpha = 1.0f;
                pagesListVisible = YES;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                if (finished) {
                    scvPages.contentSize = scvPages_ContentSize;
                }
            }];
    }   

}
```

Here is the method I use to hide the pages list (and other views)

```
- (void)resetNavigationControls {
if (pagesListVisible) {
        [btnPages setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        hidePages = YES;
        // Nascondi la lista delle pagine.
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7
                         animations:^ 
         {
             scvPages.frame = CGRectMake(0, 960, 768, 0);
             scvPages.alpha = 0.0f;
         } 
            completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             if (finished) {
                 scvPages.contentSize = scvPages_ContentSize;
                 pagesListVisible = NO;
            }
         }
         ];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to bet, it would be on your scrollview being zoomed and not resetting the affine transform back to the identity. I'm no expert on such things, but that's where I would look.

If your scrollview isn't zooming at all, then I'd recommend logging the values of scrollview.bounces, .bouncesZoom, .alwaysBounceVertical and .alwaysBounceHorizontal on a timer from the beginning of your app and see if anything changes the values while triggering your bug. You want all to be YES all the time, of course.

Good luck,

Damien

Comment: I looked for those properties in my code. There is no reference to any of these properties (I used CMD+F to find.. no results).

Comment: You might not be referencing them, but if they change that could be a problem. How about the zooming - are you zooming at all?

Comment: the problem is that... when I change the presentation, why the problem persists? The view should be unloaded and recreated.

Comment: Whatever breaks the UIScrollView doesn't fix it...that's actually not a huge surprise. Can you verify you aren't zooming at all? Also just occurred to me, if the bounds don't match the contentSize it could potentially cause problems.

Comment: Nope... the problem persists... but I found how to reproduce it: I am doing an animiation to open the list of pages, and an animation to close it. When I open a presentation which contains lots of pages (so that the contentSize of the UIScrollView > the width of the UIScrollView), I get no problem. But When I open and close the pages list in a presentation which only has one page, the problem begins. I wrote the code I am using to perform the animation+